# Django annotate on a "custom field" with django-sorting

Tags: django, sorting, annotate

I have to show entries by date in a django app and i'm a bit blocked :
Here's an example of my models:

```
class Event(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme)
    ...

class Date(models.Model):  
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)  
    start = models.DateField()  
    end = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['start', 'end']
        unique_together = ['event', 'start']
```

I got a view that take all the events in the database : Event.objects.all()

and then in a template i show the list of events with their theme and other stuffs like the date start.
I would like to show in the list the first "future" date, that's easy with a custom method on the event model:

```
def get_first_future_date(self):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    dates = self.date_set.filter(end__gte=today)
    if dates:
        return dates[0]
```

That method the first future date or the oldest date that isn't finished.
`Here's the problem : I would like to show that field in my template and be able to sort it with django-sorting.`

Django-sorting uses {% anchor arg %} to do it but i don't know how to manage that field in it...
How would you do that???

Thanks by advance for any answer.

Comment: I am stuck in the same situation. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, why would you sort the queryset by the `end` field when `get_first_future_date` returns just one instance of Event ?

Well, I've never used django-sorting, but I assume I would do

```
events = Event.objects.all() # or filter(...)
# pass events to the template context
```

and then in the template

```
{% load sorting_tags %}
{% autosort events %}
<thead>
   <th>{% anchor start Starting at %}</th>
   <th>{% anchor end Ending at %}</th>
    ...
</thead>
{% for event in events %}
<tr>
    <td>{{event.start}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it what you were asking for ?